# How to set each object of an array as a parameter to a function called in a row of dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, parameters, dynamic-tables

```
<html>
     <body>
         <table>
              <tbody id="tblBody">
              </tbody>
         </table>

<script>    
let t = [{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4}]
    populate(t)
    
    function populate(t) {
        
        let tbody = document.getElementById('tblBody')
        let tableHtml = ''
        t.forEach(obj => {
            
            tableHtml += `
            <tr>
                <td>${obj.a}</td>
                <td>${obj.b}</td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick= "editT(${JSON.stringify(obj)})">Edit</button>    
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
        `
        });
        tbody.innerHTML = tableHtml
    }
    
    const editT = (obj) => {
        let parsedObj = JSON.parse(obj)
        console.log(parsedObj)
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**But I am unable to set obj as a parameter of function editT().**
Is there any way to set object as parameter so that each object can be edited by clicking button in a dynamic table. Actual object has many key value pairs.

Comment: I think that editT function is not visible in the scope of populate function. Try to move editT definition inside of the populate function.

Comment: If the editT() function is localized it will not be accessed from a dynamic row.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to pass the object (stringified) index to the onclick function.

```js
let t = [{
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}, {
  a: 3,
  b: 4
}]
populate(t)

function populate(t) {

  let tbody = document.getElementById('tblBody')
  let tableHtml = ''
  t.forEach((obj,index) => {

    tableHtml += `
                <tr>
                    <td>${obj.a}</td>
                    <td>${obj.b}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button onclick= "editT(${+index})">Edit</button>    
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
            `
  });
  tbody.innerHTML = tableHtml
}

const editT = (index) => {
  const obj = t[index];
  console.log(obj)
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody id="tblBody">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

**Edit**

I don't love the idea of encoding the param to `editT`, because that makes a copy of the parameter. If `editT` is really going to "edit t", `t` must either be passed as a param or be in the enclosing scope.

Anyway, if the OP really prefers a copy of the selected object via string encoding, here's a snippet that does that. The error in the OP was caused by assigning the onclick prop to a string, rather than a function.

```js
let t = [{
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}, {
  a: 3,
  b: 4
}]
populate(t)

function populate(t) {

  let tbody = document.getElementById('tblBody')
  let tableHtml = ''
  t.forEach((obj,index) => {
    let expr = `editT(${JSON.stringify(obj)})`;
    tableHtml += `
                <tr>
                    <td>${obj.a}</td>
                    <td>${obj.b}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button onclick=${expr}>Edit</button>    
                    </td>
                </tr>
            `
  });
  tbody.innerHTML = tableHtml
}

const editT = (obj) => {
  console.log("note, this is a copy of the object in t:", obj)
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody id="tblBody">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Surely it would work the way I did this query. But actually 't' itself is a parameter to another function which wraps it all except the editT() function. The editT() function must be a global function to be accessed from a dynamic row. So 't' cannot be accessed as a global object in the function editT(). My problem is how to stringify each obj so that it can fit as a parameter in function editT().

Comment: Hi @Satyendra - added a snippet that fixes only the problem as posed. I worry that you still won't have what you need, because, as I noted in the edit, the encoded param is a copy of the object in the array.